# Display user role Name - not slug

Tags: php, user-roles

```
<?php global $current_user; echo array_shift($current_user->roles);>
```

Using this i can display user role slug but i want to display Name of the role. Any suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: echo $current_user->display_name; ?

Comment: @RiddleMeThis that would display the display name of the user, e.g. for `tomjn` it would be "Tom J Nowell". The OP doesn't want that though, they have `admin` and want `"Administrator"`

Comment: right.  I totally misread the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress does not (currently) have a *global* function (e.g. `get_role_name()`) for getting the role *name* (e.g. `Shop Manager` for `shop-manager` or maybe `shop_manager` etc.), but you can easily get (and then display) it like so:

```php
$role = 'shop-manager'; // the role slug; it's up to you how to get the value..

$role_name = $role ? wp_roles()->get_names()[ $role ] : '';
/* Or directly access WP_Roles::$role_names:
$role_name = $role ? wp_roles()->role_names[ $role ] : '';
*/

echo $role_name;
```

References: [`wp_roles()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_roles/) and the [`WP_Roles` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_roles/).

#### Some Additional Notes

1. Be careful when using `array_shift()` - it does return the value but also removes the original item from the source array, so in your case, the next time you access `$current_user->roles`, it would be empty or no longer contains the user's role.
2. Just as with the current *post* where it's a better practice to access the post object/data using `get_post()`, it's also recommended to use [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) to get the current user object/data instead of relying upon the global `$current_user` variable.

   And if your code runs only if the current user is authenticated/logged-in, then a shortcut for getting the user role is `$role = wp_get_current_user()->roles[0];` :)

*PS: Big thanks to [@WacławJacek](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/115216/wac%c5%82aw-jacek) for his helpful comment! =)*

Comment: Be careful when using `array_shift()` though - it does return the value but also removes it from the source array. You can use `$current_user->roles[0]` instead. You can also use `wp_get_current_user()` instead of using the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
global $current_user;
$role = $current_user->roles[0];
$role_name = $role ? wp_roles()->get_names()[ $role ] : '';
echo $role_name;
?>
```

Works like a charm

Comment: It's quite bizarre that you unaccepted my answer after it's accepted for over a month - is my answer no longer working?... But anyway, thanks for your previous support.

Comment: sorry :) your answer helped